# Pointer to functions in a STL map

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function-pointers

I am facing a problem regarding function pointers syntax. I have used these before but the situation i have make things totally not obvious anymore.

So, i am designing a factory that creates nodes for a game. The factory's create method has 2 overloads as shown here:

- AbstractNode* create(AbstractNode::TYPE) const;
- AbstractNode* create(AbstractNode::TYPE, Vector3) const;

In the factory, i have private methods that will take care of the creation process (based on the type of the node) here are the two methods that create a ball:

- AbstractNode* createBall() const;
- AbstractNode* createBall(Vector3) const;

And finally here are both maps in which i store all the function pointers. These maps will redirect the call to the correct create method (if possible of course)

```
typedef AbstractNode* (*Functor)(void);
typedef AbstractNode* (*FunctorPosition)(Vector3);

map<unsigned int, Functor> functors_;
<unsigned int, FunctorPosition> functorsPosition_;
```

Now, my question is, what would be the syntax to add function pointers in both maps.

Here is my last attempt, which doesn't compile and throws the error below:

```
functors_.insert(make_pair(AbstractNode::NAME_BALL, &createBall));
```

**The error shown:**

```
No instance of function template std::make_pair matches the argument list
Argument types are (const unsigned int, <unkown-type>)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note there's a difference between pointers to functions and pointers to (non-static) member functions. See [parashift C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html)

Comment: This this has nothing to do whatsoever with `std::map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createBall` is a non-static member function. Pointer-to-member-function types are different from pointer-to-function types.

So, the type of `&createBall` isn't `AbstractNode* (*)(void)`, it's `AbstractNode* (Factory::*)(void)const`, where `Factory` is the name of the class it appears in. If you want a pointer-to-member-function then change the type `Functor` (and make sure that when you come to call it, you have an instance of `Factory` to call it on). If you want a pointer-to-function then change `createBall` to a static member function.

Furthermore, the compiler can't work out what type of pair you want to create, since `&createBall` is ambiguous between the two overloads named `createBall`. Once you have the type `Functor` correct, you can write:

```
functors_.insert(make_pair(AbstractNode::NAME_BALL, (Functor)&createBall));
functorsPosition_.insert(make_pair(AbstractNode::NAME_BALL, (FunctorPosition)&createBall));
```

The cast tells the compiler which function you mean -- this is a special exception to the usual rule in C++ that the type of a subexpression `&createBall` doesn't depend on the context it appears in.

I think you should be able to avoid the cast with:

```
functors_[AbstractNode::NAME_BALL] = &createBall;
```

since assignment of a pointer to an overloaded function is likewise a special case. But I'm too lazy to check it.

Comment: you are absolutely right, i forgot to declare the functions as static, ill give that a try

Comment: @DanyKhalife: you'll need the cast too, the special rule doesn't let the compiler deduce all the way inwards from what type of pair `insert` needs, to what template arguments `make_pair` should have.

Comment: C-style casts really make me itchy … :-/

Comment: yes i had the cast too, must have forgotten to put that in the question. Thanks a lot @SteveJessop !

Comment: Oh and i tested the second suggestion (without the cast), it also worked, i didn't think it would that's why i was using insert but that just makes it even easier :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: True, `static_cast` is safer since (unlike the `reinterpret_cast` that the C-style cast would fall back on if it had to) it won't convert to an unrelated pointer-to-function or pointer-to-member-function type.